# Rails Helper If statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a helper that will read an integer and set the string that goes with it and also the class. I thought it would be something like this...

```
def credit_status(customer)
if customer.stop_flag == 0
  <span class="badge badge-success">Active</span>

elsif customer.stop_flag == 1
  <span class="badge badge-warning">Closed</span>

elsif customer.stop_flag == 2
  <span class="badge badge-warning">Hard Stop</span>

elsif customer.stop_flag == 3
  <span class="badge badge-danger">Closed</span>
end
end
```

But I get this error

```
/home/ec2-user/environment/rialto-crm/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected '<' <span class="badge badge-danger ^ /home/ec2-user/environment/rialto-crm/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:55: unterminated regexp meets end of file /home/ec2-user/environment/rialto-crm/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: ruby is trying to interpret `<span class="badge badge-success">Active</span>` as code. You'll need to put it in a string, possibly with `.html_safe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would be tempted to do something along the lines of:

```
STOP_FLAG_MAPPINGS = {
  '0' => {
    class: 'success',
    label: 'Active'
  },
  '1' => {
    class: 'warning',
    label: 'Closed'
  },
  '2' => {
    class: 'warning',
    label: 'Hard Stop'
  },
  '3' => {
    class: 'danger',
    label: 'Closed'
  }
}

def credit_status(customer)
  content_tag(
    :span, 
    STOP_FLAG_MAPPINGS[customer.stop_flag.to_s][:label],
    class: "badge badge-#{STOP_FLAG_MAPPINGS[customer.stop_flag.to_s][:class]}"
  )
end
```

Comment: Hi there @jvillian If I wanted the label to come from a table called lookups, what would be the best way